# select entire value of a cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column full of data with multiple lines inside a single cell like below:

[image]

I am looping through all the cells in the column and I have to select values inside every cell and search it in another sheet.I know i can split the cell value using the Split() function in vba.

But where I am struck is I am unable to select the whole value of the cell and parse it as input to the split () function. Here is my sample code where i am struck:

```
 For Each C in Range ("A1:A" & ltrow)
     If C.Value <> "" Then
        SrcStrng = C.Value
        TextArray () = Split(SrcStrng)
        .....
        ........
 .....
```

The problem I face here is in SrcStrng only the first value inside the cell for example in the first cell only t#234 is getting stored, so in split string only that is passed and it is not split properly, so I am unable to search t*567. It happens for every cell.

And also in the third cell, i want to parse only the value t#345 inside the loop for searching, neglecting L1:, I am struck with that too.

Could someone help me with this please.

Comment: How do you Dim TextArray? You should "Dim TextArray() as String". Then, when you go to use Split, do "TextArray = Split(SrcStrng)"

Comment: Also, if you make the column width much wider (drag the right side of the column in Excel), do your values still appear on separate lines, or do they end up with multiple values on one line?

Comment: @RichHolton I did declared TextArray () as string and the text in second line are entered with "Alt+enter" in a new line inside the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to show how this can be done. Use `chr(10)` as delimiter

```
Sub t()
    Dim str As String
    str = Range("A1").Value

    Dim parts As Variant
    parts = Split(str, Chr(10))

    For i = LBound(parts) To UBound(parts)
        MsgBox (parts(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA has a built-in constant for line-feed `vbLf`, that makes the code more readable and faster than using the `Chr` function with a magic number.

Comment: @ThunderFrame chr(10) indicates only 10 characters from the cell it will split right ?

Comment: @S6633d No. Chr(10) is a function that returns a character string that has one character -- the character with the ASCII code 10. That's a special character known as LineFeed. It's the character that is inserted into the characters in an Excel cell when you press Alt+enter. The second parameter in Split is the character you want to split on. If you don't specify it, it defaults to blank (or space), which you can specify like this: " ", or with Char(32).. You will want to use Split like nightcrawler23 does, above.

Comment: @ThunderFrame, i new about vbCrLf, which didnot work. Chr(10) was what i could remember. Thanks for the info. The code works with vbLf also